# Deployed app on Heroku Internal Server Error

Tags: heroku, deployment

I have a Python, Flask app that also uses PostgreSQL.

When I try to launch my app on Heroku I get this error:
`Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`
I'm fairly certain that the build and deploy went through successfully. I can see on the page for my project "Build succeeded" and "Deployed".

I've checked my env and the config vars on Heroku to make sure they are correct and they are. I had an issue initially with creating the build. I would get this error

```
[remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
```

I believe I fixed it by changing the content in runtime.txt from `python-3.9.4` to `python-3.11.3` because the one I had was not compatible apparently on Heroku.
However if I'm honest I spent hours running through a bunch of issues deploying this app and tried a lot of different things so I'm not sure if that is what allowed me to Deploy the app initially.

I looked on several other posts that seemingly had similar issues on this site but a lot of them boiled down to "read the logs." The problem here is I don't really understand what I'm looking at.

Here are the application logs on Heroku. I also tried `heroku logs --tail` in the terminal but again got another large spew of stuff I don't understand.

```
2023-05-05T20:27:02.830983+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^
2023-05-05T20:27:02.830983+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:27:02.830985+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.username AS users_username, users.password_hash AS users_password_hash 
2023-05-05T20:27:02.830986+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM users 
2023-05-05T20:27:02.830986+00:00 app[web.1]: WHERE users.username = %(username_1)s 
2023-05-05T20:27:02.830986+00:00 app[web.1]:  LIMIT %(param_1)s]
2023-05-05T20:27:02.830993+00:00 app[web.1]: [parameters: {'username_1': 'favicon.ico', 'param_1': 1}]
2023-05-05T20:27:02.830994+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
2023-05-05T20:27:02.832217+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.7.17 - - [05/May/2023:20:27:02 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://wolf-collector.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-05-05T20:27:02.834690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wolf-collector.herokuapp.com request_id=623b5da1-f91d-4469-8773-a9a67bbf61dc fwd="47.157.140.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=463 protocol=https
2023-05-05T20:31:09.974556+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=wolf-collector.herokuapp.com request_id=3c4c8153-9282-41ed-9f21-e3924dc227a8 fwd="47.157.140.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=463 protocol=https
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973408+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-05-05 20:31:09,972] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973422+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973422+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1808, in _execute_context
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973423+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973430+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973430+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973430+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "wolves" does not exist
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973431+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM wolves ORDER BY wolves.date DESC 
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973431+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973431+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973431+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973432+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973432+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973432+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973435+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973435+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973435+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973435+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973436+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973436+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973436+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973436+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973436+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973437+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973437+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973437+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973437+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/myapp/core/views.py", line 11, in index
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973438+00:00 app[web.1]:     wolves = Wolves.query.order_by(Wolves.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=6)
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973438+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973438+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 491, in paginate
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973438+00:00 app[web.1]:     items = self.limit(per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page).all()
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973438+00:00 app[web.1]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973439+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2759, in all
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973439+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._iter().all()
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973439+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973439+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2894, in _iter
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973439+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = self.session.execute(
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973440+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973440+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1692, in execute
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973440+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973440+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973440+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1620, in _execute_20
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973440+00:00 app[web.1]:     return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973440+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973441+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973441+00:00 app[web.1]:     return connection._execute_clauseelement(
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973441+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1487, in _execute_clauseelement
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973442+00:00 app[web.1]:     ret = self._execute_context(
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973442+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1851, in _execute_context
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973442+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2032, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973443+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.raise_(
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973443+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973443+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973443+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1808, in _execute_context
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973443+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973443+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973443+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973444+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "wolves" does not exist
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973444+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM wolves ORDER BY wolves.date DESC 
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973444+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973444+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973450+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT wolves.id AS wolves_id, wolves.date AS wolves_date, wolves.title AS wolves_title, wolves.text AS wolves_text, wolves.user_id AS wolves_user_id 
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973450+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM wolves ORDER BY wolves.date DESC 
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973450+00:00 app[web.1]:  LIMIT %(param_1)s OFFSET %(param_2)s]
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973450+00:00 app[web.1]: [parameters: {'param_1': 6, 'param_2': 0}]
2023-05-05T20:31:09.973451+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
2023-05-05T20:31:09.974755+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.16.107 - - [05/May/2023:20:31:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181623+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-05-05 20:31:10,180] ERROR in app: Exception on /favicon.ico [GET]
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181626+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181627+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1808, in _execute_context
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181628+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181628+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181629+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181629+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "users" does not exist
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181630+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM users 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181630+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181630+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181630+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181631+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181632+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181632+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181639+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181639+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181639+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181640+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181640+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181640+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181641+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181641+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181641+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181641+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181642+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181642+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181642+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/myapp/users/views.py", line 76, in user_posts
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181642+00:00 app[web.1]:     user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181643+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181643+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 425, in first_or_404
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181643+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.first()
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181643+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181643+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2810, in first
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181643+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.limit(1)._iter().first()
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181643+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181644+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2894, in _iter
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181644+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = self.session.execute(
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181644+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181644+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1692, in execute
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181644+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181645+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181645+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1620, in _execute_20
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181645+00:00 app[web.1]:     return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181645+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181645+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181645+00:00 app[web.1]:     return connection._execute_clauseelement(
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181646+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181646+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1487, in _execute_clauseelement
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181646+00:00 app[web.1]:     ret = self._execute_context(
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181646+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181646+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1851, in _execute_context
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181646+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181647+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2032, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181647+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.raise_(
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181647+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181647+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181647+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1808, in _execute_context
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181647+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181648+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181648+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181648+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "users" does not exist
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181648+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM users 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181648+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181648+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181650+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.username AS users_username, users.password_hash AS users_password_hash 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181650+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM users 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181651+00:00 app[web.1]: WHERE users.username = %(username_1)s 
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181651+00:00 app[web.1]:  LIMIT %(param_1)s]
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181654+00:00 app[web.1]: [parameters: {'username_1': 'favicon.ico', 'param_1': 1}]
2023-05-05T20:31:10.181654+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
2023-05-05T20:31:10.182923+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.16.107 - - [05/May/2023:20:31:10 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://wolf-collector.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-05-05T20:31:10.183797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wolf-collector.herokuapp.com request_id=f6192e75-5294-4ffa-a711-c1be7739dc5d fwd="47.157.140.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=463 protocol=https
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "wolves" does not exist"—are you using database migrations? Have you applied them?